# Why isn't "so that" possible in "so [that] as not to wake the baby"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> We were silent **so** as not to wake the baby.

(From ['So & So That' Quiz](https://www.usingenglish.com/quizzes/295.html))

Why does "so that" not work here? That is a purpose we were silent because we did not want to wake the baby so "so that" should work here. It is a result of being silent not an effect.

Comment: 'So that' must be followed by an intended conditional result, so you you could say 'We were silent **so that** we would not wake the baby, **so that** the baby would not wake', etc.

Comment: An effect is a result.

Comment: **so as [not] to** is sometimes considered to be [an idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/so+as+to).  Idioms are fixed expressions, and generally that means you can't change them. They also sometimes have a meaning which is not literal, so they often don't appear to make sense, especially if you try to identify the meaning of the constituent words separately. Don't mess with an idiom!

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, *so that* must be followed by a finite clause, while *so as (not) to* must be followed by an infinitival clause.

Often they are interchangeable, but there is a difference, in that *so that* introduces a consequence, but not necessarily an intended consequence; but *so as (not) to* is expressing a purpose.

> He insisted on telling me the whole story, so that I missed my train.

does not necessarily mean that he intended me to miss my train: he might have, or he might not even have known that I was catching a train.

> He insisted on telling me the whole story, so as to make me miss my train.

usually means that he knew I was catching a train and deliberately made me miss it.